# Getting file extension of unknown file name

Tags: php, file-extension

I want to get the file extension of a file however the file name increments so I could have file_01_XX.jpg...how could I get the extension of a file where I don't know the full file name but I know the start of it?

If you could help me that would be great. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function like this:

```
$parts = pathinfo('your file name');
echo $parts['extension'];
```

> I want to get the file extension of a file however the file name
>   increments so I could have file_01_XX.jpg...how could I get the
>   extension of a file where I don't know the full file name but I know
>   the start of it?

Whatever file name it is, this will give you the extension :)